# Fonts not looking the same on Mac in Office 2016 & Office 2011

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, fonts

I just installed Office 2016 on my Mac running Sierra.  For the same document, the fonts look different opened in Word 2016 (left side) and in Word 2011 (right side).
The left side looks a bit crisper but the edges seem jagged. The right side is smoother and easier on my eyes.

How can I make Word 2016 look like Word 2011?

[image: Side By Side Comparison 2016 vs 2011]

Comment: The difference I see in your screenshots is that 2016 is only doing old school pixel-by-pixel antialiasing, whereas 2011 is doing sub-pixel antialiasing. Unfortunately this seems to be a well known problem in Office 2013 and later, and it sounds like there's no known fix. This bug may only be triggered by some documents, or even some paragraphs of some documents. I won't post this as an Answer, in hopes someone else knows a real answer. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/subpixel-antialiasing-doesnt-work-on-certain-docx/6c6b4cf6-f86f-4704-9e04-493e91e0cecc

Answer (score 0):

Removing the watermark, even if it doesn't exist, got rid of the pixelation.
In the top menu choose Insert then Watermark. Choose No Watermark and OK.

I saw this in a different question about excel. I have no idea what the watermark or lack there of has to do with how the font is displayed.